# laravel return '?' instead of '1' in WHERE clause

Tags: laravel

```
$datas=Elan::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('status', 1)->take(4)->toSql();    
       dd($datas);
```

I wrote query in "laravel 5.2". I displayed it as sql query with function **toSql()**
and the result is:

```
"select * from `els` where `status` = ? order by `created_at` desc limit 4"
```

you can see that there is ? mark. this is why my query doesn't work. why does it return me ? instead of one. I also tried it like this '1' same result.

Comment: it is not returning ?, ? is placeholder for the value. just write the eloquent query as `$datas=Elan::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(4)->get();`

Comment: this is the expected behavior of toSql(). If you need to see the full sql check the mysql query log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read about bindings if you want to understand what does `?` mean.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug and watch queries, you can install this debugbar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: fixed it with whereRaw('`status` = 1')

Answer (score 0):

> `?` is used for Parameter binding which prevent against SQL injection.

If you want to see the raw SQL query which is executed with parameters values, try the below code:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$datas=Elan::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('status', 1)->take(4)->get(); 
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Hope this helps!